# how to select data from ms access database in c# By today date

Tags: c#, database, date, oledb

I want to know how to select data from MS Access database in C# from today date.

I can select data from database between date but when I select today date and  get data it's show me blank.

Please help me. Here is my Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "Today Report")
            {
                DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dsa.Tables.Add(dt);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Date] from [Total] Where [Date] = #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "#", VCON);
                da.Fill(dt);
                CrystalReport4 MYREPORT = new CrystalReport4();
                MYREPORT.SetDataSource(dt);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = MYREPORT;
                VCON.Close();
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "Custom Report")
            {
                DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dsa.Tables.Add(dt);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Date] from [Total] Where [Date] between #" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "# AND #" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString() + "#", VCON);
                da.Fill(dt);
                CrystalReport4 MYREPORT = new CrystalReport4();
                MYREPORT.SetDataSource(dt);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = MYREPORT;
                VCON.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry! File was not Found:Please Try Again", "Daily Report", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why did you add `skype` and `expert-system` tags?

Comment: well, maybe there is no data for today. or maybe you are confusing OleDB by passing a string rather than date. Or maybe the time in the picker doesnt match.

Comment: There is data but it''s not showing and am not confuse to oledb by passing a string rather than date and am not using time in datetimepicker or not in my database